# Original version of Raghupati Raghav Raja Ram bhajan?

Tags: bhakti, resource

I would like to know about the original source and version and the author of the famous bhajan **Raghupati Raghav Raja Ram**. This bhajan was later edited and popularized by Gandhi. This was widely attributed to his attempts to bring about  restoration of friendly relations but it is anybody’s guess how many muslims would have actually sung this. Compare this with the confusion that it brought about in the minds of Hindus.

Please cite authentic references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original lyrics of Raghupati Raghava Rajaaram are written by **Sri Lakshamanacharya** in a religious text titled **Shri Nama Ramayanam**

Source: [Raghupati Raghav Rajaram – The Original Lyrics](https://arisebharat.com/2018/06/25/raghupati-raghav-rajaram-the-original-lyrics/)

Original text of Bhajan:

> ```
> रघुपति राघव राजाराम
> पतित पावन सीताराम
> सुंदर विग्रह मेघश्याम
> गंगा तुलसी शालग्राम
> भद्रगिरीश्वर सीताराम
> भगत-जनप्रिय सीताराम
> जानकीरमणा सीताराम
> जयजय राघव सीताराम
> ```

These devotional songs falls in category called as **Nām Jap / नाम जप** (chanting of various names of any god / goddess).

Gandhi had nothing to do with the lyrics of this Bhajan. This bhajan was already popular among common folks (Hindu devotees) before him.
However, only thing Gandhi did was tempering the original lyrics to suit his vested political interests.

**how many Muslims would have actually sung this?**

Honestly, Very handful of people might notice the Independence time and Allah has nothing to do with this Bhajan, Don't know the Gandhi intension behind temper the original words? May be restore friendly atmosphere between Hindus and Muslims which didn't happen later.

[image]

Comment: We are waiting for your answer here: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/2021-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire :)

Comment: @Rickross I would like to withdraw my nomination, I can’t continue for some personal reasons. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

Original song given [here](https://te.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B0%B0%E0%B0%98%E0%B1%81%E0%B0%AA%E0%B0%A4%E0%B0%BF_%E0%B0%B0%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%98%E0%B0%B5_%E0%B0%B0%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%9C%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%B0%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%AE%E0%B1%8D).

> Raghupati raghava rajaram
>
> Patita paavana sitaram
>
> Sundara vigraha meghashyam
>
> Ganga tulasi salagram
>
> Bhadra girishwara sitaram
>
> Bhakata janapriya sitaram
>
> Janaki ramana sitaram
>
> Jaya jaya raghava sitaram

The last two lines are sometimes read as -

> जय रघुनंदन जय सिया राम जानकी वल्लभ सीताराम

Answer (score 2):

Original "रघुपति राघव राजा राम" Bhajana which is written by Lakshamanacharya. In this small treatise/bhajana, 108 names of Lord Rama are described based on Seven chapters of Ramayana as follows:

> श्री नाम रामायणं (लघुग्रंथ) ॥ बालकाण्डम् ॥
>
> शुद्धब्रह्मपरात्पर राम् ॥१॥ कालात्मकपरमेश्वर राम् ॥२॥
>   शेषतल्पसुखनिद्रित राम् ॥३॥ ब्रह्माद्यामरप्रार्थित राम् ॥४॥ राम् राम्
>   जय राजा राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> चण्डकिरणकुलमण्डन राम् ॥५॥ श्रीमद्दशरथनन्दन राम् ॥६॥ कौसल्यासुखवर्धन
>   राम् ॥७॥ विश्वामित्रप्रियधन राम् ॥८॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम्
>   राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> घोरताटकाघातक राम् ॥९॥ मारीचादिनिपातक राम् ॥१०॥ कौशिकमखसंरक्षक राम्
>   ॥११॥ श्रीमदहल्योद्धारक राम् ॥१२॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम् राम् जय
>   सीता राम् ।
>
> गौतममुनिसंपूजित राम् ॥१३॥ सुरमुनिवरगणसंस्तुत राम् ॥१४॥
>   नाविकधावितमृदुपद राम् ॥१५॥ मिथिलापुरजनमोहक राम् ॥१६॥ राम् राम् जय राजा
>   राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> विदेहमानसरञ्जक राम् ॥१७॥ त्र्यंबककार्मुकभञ्जक राम् ॥१८॥
>   सीतार्पितवरमालिक राम् ॥१९॥ कृतवैवाहिककौतुक राम् ॥२०॥ राम् राम् जय राजा
>   राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> भार्गवदर्पविनाशक राम् ॥२१॥ श्रीमदयोध्यापालक राम् ॥२२॥
>
> ॥ अयोध्याकाण्डम् ॥
>
> अगणितगुणगणभूषित राम् ॥२३॥ अवनीतनयाकामित राम् ॥२४॥ राम् राम् जय राजा
>   राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> राकाचन्द्रसमानन राम् ॥२५॥ पितृवाक्याश्रितकानन राम् ॥२६॥
>   प्रियगुहविनिवेदितपद राम् ॥२७॥ तत्क्षालितनिजमृदुपद राम् ॥२८ राम् राम्
>   जय राजा राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> भरद्वाजमुखानन्दक राम् ॥२९॥ चित्रकूटाद्रिनिकेतन राम् ॥३०॥
>   दशरथसन्ततचिन्तित राम् ॥३१॥ कैकेयीतनयार्थित राम् ॥३२॥ राम् राम् जय राजा
>   राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> विरचितनिजपितृकर्मक राम् ॥३३॥ भरतार्पितनिजपादुक राम् ॥३४॥
>
> ॥ अरण्यकाण्डम् ॥
>
> दण्डकवनजनपावन राम् ॥३५॥ दुष्टविराधविनाशन राम् ॥३६॥ राम् राम् जय राजा
>   राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> शरभङ्गसुतीक्ष्णार्चित राम् ॥३७॥ अगस्त्यानुग्रहवर्धित राम् ॥३८
>   गृध्राधिपसंसेवित राम् ॥३९॥ पञ्चवटीतटसुस्थित राम् ॥४०॥ राम् राम् जय
>   राजा राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> शूर्पणखार्तिविधायक राम् ॥४१॥ खरदूषणमुखसूदक राम् ॥४२॥ सीताप्रियहरिणानुग
>   राम् ॥४३॥ मारीचार्तिकृदाशुग राम् ॥४४॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम्
>   राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> विनष्टसीतान्वेषक राम् ॥४५॥ गृध्राधिपगतिदायक राम् ॥४६॥ शबरीदत्तफलाशन
>   राम् ॥४७॥ कबन्धबाहुच्छेदक राम् ॥४८॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम् राम्
>   जय सीता राम् ।
>
> ॥ किष्किन्धाकाण्डम् ॥
>
> हनुमत्सेवितनिजपद राम् ॥४९॥ नतसुग्रीवाभीष्टद राम् ॥५०॥ गर्वितवालिसंहारक
>   राम् ॥५१॥ वानरदूतप्रेषक राम् ॥५२॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम् राम्
>   जय सीता राम् ।
>
> हितकरलक्ष्मणसंयुत राम् ॥५३॥
>
> ॥ सुन्दरकाण्डम् ॥
>
> कपिवरसन्ततसंस्मृत राम् ॥५४॥ तद्‍गतिविघ्नध्वंसक राम् ॥५५॥
>   सीताप्राणाधारक राम् ॥५६॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता
>   राम् ।
>
> दुष्टदशाननदूषित राम् ॥५७॥ शिष्टहनूमद्‍भूषित राम् ॥५८॥ सीतावेदितकाकावन
>   राम् ॥५९॥ कृतचूडामणिदर्शन राम् ॥६०॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम् राम्
>   जय सीता राम् ।
>
> कपिवरवचनाश्वासित राम् ॥६१॥
>
> ॥ युध्दकाण्डम् ॥
>
> रावणनिधनप्रस्थित राम् ॥६२॥ वानरसैन्यसमावृत राम् ॥६३॥ शोषितसरिदीशार्थित
>   राम् ॥६४॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> विभीषणाभयदायक राम् ॥६५॥ पर्वतसेतुनिबन्धक राम् ॥६६॥ कुम्भकर्णशिरच्छेदक
>   राम् ॥६७॥ राक्षससङ्घविमर्दक राम् ॥६८॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम्
>   राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> अहिमहिरावणचारण राम् ॥६९॥ संहृतदशमुखरावण राम् ॥७०॥ विधिभवमुखसुरसंस्तुत
>   राम् ॥७१॥ खस्थितदशरथवीक्षित राम् ॥७२॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम्
>   राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> सीतादर्शनमोदित राम् ॥७३॥ अभिषिक्तविभीषणनत राम् ॥७४॥ पुष्पकयानारोहण
>   राम् ॥७५॥ भरद्वाजादिनिषेवण राम् ॥७६॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम्
>   राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> भरतप्राणप्रियकर राम् ॥७७॥ साकेतपुरीभूषण राम् ॥७८॥ सकलस्वीयसमानत राम्
>   ॥७९॥ रत्नलसत्पीठास्थित राम् ॥८०॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम् राम् जय
>   सीता राम् ।
>
> पट्टाभिषेकालंकृत राम् ॥८१॥ पार्थिवकुलसम्मानित राम् ॥८२॥
>   विभीषणार्पितरङ्गक राम् ॥८३॥ कीशकुलानुग्रहकर राम् ॥८४॥ राम् राम् जय
>   राजा राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> सकलजीवसंरक्षक राम् ॥८५॥ समस्तलोकाधारक राम् ॥८६॥
>
> ॥ उत्तरकाण्डम् ॥
>
> आगतमुनिगणसंस्तुत राम् ॥८७॥ विश्रुतदशकण्ठोद्भव राम् ॥८८॥ राम् राम् जय
>   राजा राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> सीतालिङ्गननिर्वृत राम् ॥८९॥ नीतिसुरक्षितजनपद राम् ॥९० विपिनत्याजितजनकज
>   राम् ॥९१॥ कारितलवणासुरवध राम् ॥९२॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम् राम्
>   जय सीता राम् ।
>
> स्वर्गतशम्बुकसंस्तुत राम् ॥९३॥ स्वतनयकुशलवनन्दित राम् ॥९४॥
>   अश्वमेधक्रतुदीक्षित राम् ॥९५॥ कालावेदितसुरपद राम् ॥९६॥ राम् राम् जय
>   राजा राम् । राम् राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> आयोध्यकजनमुक्तिद राम् ॥९७॥ विधिमुखविबुधानन्दक राम् ॥९८॥ तेजोमयनिजरूपक
>   राम् ॥९९॥ संसृतिबन्धविमोचक राम् ॥१००॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम्
>   राम् जय सीता राम् ।
>
> धर्मस्थापनतत्पर राम् ॥१०१॥ भक्तिपरायणमुक्तिद राम् ॥१०२॥ सर्वचराचरपालक
>   राम् ॥१०३॥ सर्वभवामयवारक राम् ॥१०४॥ राम् राम् जय राजा राम् । राम् राम्
>   जय सीता राम् ।
>
> वैकुण्ठालयसंस्थित राम् ॥१०५॥ नित्यानन्दपदस्थित राम् ॥१०६॥ राम् राम् जय
>   जय राजा राम् ॥१०७॥ राम् राम् जय जय सीता राम् ॥१०८॥

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE! This is an English-language site so answers must primarily be in English. See [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/2995) meta post.

Comment: I am not finding the Bhajana in quoted text. Can you clarify it whether the quoted text is a Bhajana which question is talking about?